# Download MVC File with javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a Controller.cs that returns the File like this:

```
return File(file, "application/xml");
```

Which eventually returns the file to my js as:

```
.then(function (file) {
      window.open(uri, '_blank');
      downloadFile(file);
 });
```

The window.open shows the xml file in my browser but I want to download the file that comes with it.

I tried many solutions to make it works but it seems the file is not what I expect it to be.

I tried these:

1.

```
function objToString(obj) {
    var str = '';
    for (var p in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
            str += p + '::' + obj[p] + '\n';
        }
    }
    return str;
}

console.log(objToString(file));
//Output:
0::<
1::?
2::x
3::m
4::l
5:: 
6::v
7::e
8::r
9::s
10::i
11::o
etc..
```

2:

```
console.log(file.toJSON());
//output:
Object(13799) [ "<", "?", "x", "m", "l", " ", "v", "e", "r", "s", … ]
```

3.

```
console.log(file.toString());
//output:
[object Object]
```

4.

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(file));
//output:
{"0":"<","1":"?","2":"x","3":"m","4":"l","5":" ","6":"v","7":"e","8":"r","9":"s","10":"i","11":"o","12":"n","13":"=","14":"\"","15":"1","16":".","17":"0","18":"\"","19":" ","20":"e","21":"n","etc..
```

I want to use this method to download:

```
if (window.navigator && window.navigator.msSaveBlob) {

    e.preventDefault();
    navigator.msSaveBlob(new Blob([file], { type: 'application/xml' }), "file.xml")

}
else {
    var link = document.createElement("a");
    link.download = "file.xml";
    link.href = "data:application/xml," + encodeURIComponent(file);
    link.click();
}
```

What can I do to make it work? How do I parse the file?

Comment: Try `console.log(file.constructor)` it should give you hint what type this file object is, maybe it's arrayBuffer or something like that. Then you will be able to google the methods, or use `console.dir(file)` it should give you those methods.

Comment: @jcubic It seems the file.constructor doesn't give me much more information.

It outputs this:
Resource()​
bind: function bind()​
delete: function name()​
get: function name()
​
length: 1
​
name: "Resource"
​
prototype: Object { toJSON: toJSON(), "$get": (), "$save": ()
, … }
​
query: function name()​
remove: function name()​
save: name()

Comment: I'm not sure what this object is, maybe it's something from MVC. Can you show rest of the code before `.then(function (file) {` that may show what the file is.

Answer (score 0):

Got a solution working:

```
function download(file) {

var blob = new Blob([new Uint8Array(file.data)], { type: 'application/xml' });
var name = 'Infopath.xml';

if (window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) { // for IE 11 en Edge
    window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, name);
}
else //Other browsers
{
    var URL = window.URL || window.MozURL || window.webkitURL || window.MSURL || window.OURL;

    var anchor = document.createElement('a');
    anchor.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    anchor.download = name;
    document.body.appendChild(anchor);
    anchor.target = '_blank';
    anchor.click();

    document.body.removeChild(anchor);
   }
}
```